# I am trying to add to autocomplete codeignator

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hai I am trying to add to autocomplete in Codeigniter project, but its showing 500 Internal Server Error please help me

view

```
<input class="form-control mousetrap ui-autocomplete-input" id="search_counterpart" placeholder="Enter Counterpart" name="search_counterpart" type="text">
```

jquery

```
 $("#search_counterpart").autocomplete({
source: function( request, response ) {    
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/admin/counterpartslist",
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
          search: request.term
        },
        success: function( data ) {
          response( data );
        }
      });
    }, 
  });
```

controller

```
public function counterpartslist(){
    $postData = $this->input->post();
    $Crud_model=new Crud_model;  
    $data = $this->Crud_model->getcounterparts($postData);    
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

model

```
function getcounterparts($postData){  

    $response =array();
    if(asset($postData['search'])){   
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->where("business_name like '%".$postData['search']."%' ");
        $records = $this->db->get('user_table')->result();
        foreach($records as $row ){
            $response[] = array("value"=>$row->user_id,
                                "label"=>$row->business_name);
        }
    } 
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: You **model** appears to have some comments `/*` without any closing comment `*/` So it probably does not compile

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I removed it all but still shows 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: _removed it all_ What does that mean? SHow the COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE and the code related to the error

Comment: What has `C#` got to do with this question? Please dont SPAM tags they are there to gather a specific audience to your question, if you spam tags you just get an angry audience

Comment: @RiggsFolly Removed the text  and / * symbols I commented  still shows 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Please post the relevant code as it is now then. In the Question, using the edit link

Comment: Post the error that is being encountered. If you can't see the error, go to root directory and open index.php and check the environment. If it is in production, make it development. It will be difficult to help you until you post the error.

Comment: "No response data available for this request" This is what the browser response shows      What does that mean

Comment: what version you are working on codeigniter 3 or 4

Comment: I am using Codeignator 3